# jquery tooltip on form elements

Tags: jquery, forms, tooltip

I am using jquery tooltip plugin on some of the elements in a form a form, to show the tooltip when the user clicks and focuses on the input (text field) or dropdown and hide on blur and click anywhere outside browser area.

It is working fine on the input BUT The issue I am facing is on the dropdown its showing the tooltip on hovering the dropdown.

In the first instance when it loads the page its working fine but once it shows the tooltip for that dropdown on click then on it shows it on hover...has anyone faced a similar issue.